# How do I display my stylesheet link on my page as text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a link to a stylesheet in text. 
I have looked into both the pre and the code element. I have the following code:

```
<pre>
 <code>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </code>
</pre>
```

And the following CSS:

```
pre {
white-space: pre;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}   
code {
display: block;
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #888888;
border-radius: 8px;
width: 96%;
padding: 2%;
}
```

I chose not to use the xmp tag as it didn't work with my styles and it wasn't responsive.

I have yet to see it displayed on my page without using the xmp element.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't link to a stylesheet and have the contents displayed as text with plain HTML. You'd need to put the contents into the page by hand, or use JavaScript to load the file and display it.

Comment: All css libraries are doing it though? How do they accomplish this? Example: http://purecss.io/

Comment: All CSS libraries are doing what?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. They are displaying the link in plain text on the page. I solved it with Jesus' suggestion.

Comment: As a side note, you could have simply used a web inspector in any browser to see how they did it on purecss.io

Comment: Just looking at the site's source code would've shown you how it was done.

Comment: I did on multiple sites and couldn't get any of the ways to work. The console doesn't show the html escaped characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to html escape the link definition and put in your HTML markup.

```
&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;css/style.css&quot;&gt;
```

you can try it in http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#ad-output

Comment: I think he is trying to show the css content on the document only putting the link tag in a code tag.

Comment: @Vangoso if you look at what site the OP referenced, it appears he is just trying to show the link, and Jesus's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your request but what about that?

```
link::after {
    content: attr(href);
}

link {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```